# Where to call reset method for RTKQ useMutation()?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Since RTK 1.7.0, mutation result object has a `reset()` method to unsubscribe from the state update of a mutation from another component:

```js
const [mutate, { isLoading, reset }] = useMutation({ fixedCacheKey });
```

I use it to get `isLoading` state from another component's mutation. But I don't know where to call the cleanup `reset()`:

- In the click handler:

  ```js
  await mutate()
  reset()
  ```
- Or in the cleanup

  ```js
  useEffect(() => () => reset(), [reset])
  ```

  If it's this case, then do I need to do this for both (original and subscriber) components? And this is weird: the identity of `reset` function changes after state update, so the `isLoading` is cleared right after it changes.

I think the docs about this function is not very clear. Hope someone can improve it.

I'm using React 17.0.2, RTK 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Mutations never share state between usage in different components in the fist place - unless you force that by using `fixedCacheKey`. Are you maybe trying to solve a non-problem here?

Comment: Yes I want that, and use `fixedCacheKey`. From the release note, I think that it requires manual cleanup with `reset` (although the docs doesn't mention this). Or is `reset()` only required in even more special case than `fixedCacheKey`?

Comment: I don't remember how it was back then tbh., but I would recommend updating to the current 1.9.1 - you are way behind. I assume this should just work nowadays.